# future package deprecated - issues with plan("multisession"); how can I force plan("multicore")?

Tags: r, package, future, multicore

It seems that for me at least multicore parallelisation is not working with varimpact. I tried to create an example, please see below:

I am using macOS Big Sur, MacBook Air (M1, 2020), 16 GB RAM, 8 cores
R version 4.1.0

```
# dataset
my_outcome <- runif(300, min=0, max=500)
var_1 <- as.numeric(1:300)
var_2 <- runif(300)
var_3 <- runif(300, min=0, max=1)
var_4 <- as.factor(c(rep("0",30),rep("1",270)))
var_5 <- as.factor(c(rep("0",25),rep("1",275)))
my_dataset <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5)
str(my_dataset)

# all libraries I am loading
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
library(optiRum)
library(gridExtra)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(anytime)
library(foreign)
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(Hmisc)
library(reshape2)
library(utils)
library(zoo)
library(lme4)
library(broom)
library(stats)
library(factoextra)
library(cluster)
library(pscl)
library(SuperLearner)
library(quadprog)
library(earth)
library(tmle)
library(xgboost)
library(randomForest)
library(ranger)
library(glmnet)
library(nnet)
library(kernlab)
library(KernelKnn)
library(varimpact)
library(hopach)
library(dbarts)
library(arm)
library(gam)

# Hyperparameter optimisation

# Fit elastic net with 5 different alphas: 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0.
learners_glmnet = create.Learner("SL.glmnet", detailed_names = TRUE,
                                tune = list(alpha = seq(0, 1, length.out = 5)))

# 5 configurations
learners_glmnet$names

# Random forest via ranger
learners_ranger = create.Learner("SL.ranger", detailed_names = TRUE,
                                 tune = list(mtry = c(1), ntree = c(1000), nodesize=c(1,5,10)),
                                 name_prefix = "rgr")

# 3 configurations
learners_ranger$names

# XGBoost
learners_xgboost = create.Learner("SL.xgboost", detailed_names = TRUE,
                                  tune = list(ntrees = c(500, 1000), max_depth = c(2, 4), shrinkage = c(0.001, 0.01)),
                                  name_prefix = "xgb")

# 8 configurations
learners_xgboost$names

# earth - Multivariate adaptive regression splines
learners_earth = create.Learner("SL.earth", detailed_names = TRUE,
                              tune = list(degree = c(1,2)))

# 2 configurations
learners_earth$names

# svm - support vector machine
learners_svm = create.Learner("SL.ksvm", detailed_names = TRUE,
                              tune = list(kernel = c("rbfdot", "polydot"), C = c(0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100)),
                              name_prefix = "svm")

# 10 configurations
learners_svm$names

# SL library:
Q_lib <- c("SL.mean", "SL.glm", "SL.bayesglm", learners_earth$names,
           learners_glmnet$names, "tmle.SL.dbarts2",
           "SL.rpartPrune", learners_ranger$names, learners_svm$names,
           learners_xgboost$names)

g_lib <- c("SL.mean", "SL.glm", "SL.bayesglm", learners_earth$names,
           learners_glmnet$names, "tmle.SL.dbarts2",
           "SL.rpartPrune", learners_ranger$names, learners_svm$names,
           learners_xgboost$names)


library(future)
plan("multisession")

vim <- varimpact(Y = my_outcome, data = my_dataset, Q.library = Q_lib, g.library = g_lib, family = "gaussian",
                 adjust_cutoff = NULL, V = 2)
```

As a result I get:

```
Finished pre-processing variables.

Processing results:
- Factor variables: 1 
- Numeric variables: 3 

Estimating variable importance for 1 factors.
Error estimating g using SuperLearner. Defaulting to glm
Error estimating g using SuperLearner. Defaulting to glm
Error estimating g using SuperLearner. Defaulting to glm
Error estimating g using SuperLearner. Defaulting to glm


Estimating variable importance for 3 numerics.
Error estimating g using SuperLearner. Defaulting to glm
Error in training_estimates[[bin_j]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
3: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
4: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
5: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
6: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
7: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
8: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
9: `funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.
Please use a list of either functions or lambdas: 

  # Simple named list: 
  list(mean = mean, median = median)

  # Auto named with `tibble::lst()`: 
  tibble::lst(mean, median)

  # Using lambdas
  list(~ mean(., trim = .2), ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE))
This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
```

I closed my R session and started again and obtained the same result via "snow":

```
library(RhpcBLASctl)
library(future)

cl = parallel::makeCluster(get_num_cores())
plan("cluster", workers = cl)

vim <- varimpact(Y = my_outcome, data = my_dataset, Q.library = Q_lib, g.library = g_lib, family = "gaussian",
                 adjust_cutoff = NULL, V = 2)
```

Any ideas on what might be happening?

I think this is related with plan("multisession"). If I run plan("multicore"), it does not give me those error messages, but I am not sure if it is doing anything. Also, if I run plan("multiprocess"), I get the following message:

```
Warning messages:
1: Strategy 'multiprocess' is deprecated in future (>= 1.20.0). Instead, explicitly specify either 'multisession' or 'multicore'. In the current R session, 'multiprocess' equals 'multisession'. 
2: In supportsMulticoreAndRStudio(...) :
  [ONE-TIME WARNING] Forked processing ('multicore') is not supported when running R from RStudio because it is considered unstable. For more details, how to control forked processing or not, and how to silence this warning in future R sessions, see ?parallelly::supportsMulticore
```

Comment: try ```plan(multisession, workers = cl)``` (no quotes around multisession)

Comment: Thanks @NovaEthos - just to confirm can I run that in R Studio or it has to be in the terminal?

Comment: You can try it in the script like you did before. It doesn't have to be in the terminal. I'm not sure if it will work, but I ran into a similar problem before and that's what solved it for me.

Comment: Thanks @NovaEthos. It did not work for me, I had to run plan(multicore) in R directly.

Comment: Well, glad you ended up figuring it out!